# Measuring how long it takes to draw a view in a UIViewController and all its subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

At first I wanted to use -viewWill/DidAppear but I need to know the time for all subsequent updates in all possible view controllers so I came up with a UIView subclass that is always a root view in every controller and has an instance variable for its parent VC and does this in -drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   if (self.parentViewController)  {
      [self.parentViewController resetTime];
      [self.parentViewController performSelector:@selector(measureTimeMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.0];
   }
}
```

Seems to kind of work but can I be certain that this gets called on the next event cycle? I am sure there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: I think that performSelector: with delay would call the selector on the next event cycle after all the subviews have already been drawn. The thing is, I'm not sure. As I develop this app I want to see how each solution affects the speed. I need to constantly fech stuff from a database and screens might become too complex and I want to know what solution was right and what idea was wrong, where should I use lazy loading, where should I keep stuff in memory caches and so on and on.

Answer (score 0):

You could (and should) use Inspector to measure timing issues of your CoreGraphics routines to build up your user interface.

If you have heavy draw calls in your `-drawRect:` class method it will be slower for sure then with less calls. Which is the reason why Apple suggests to avoid the use of this method if there are no continuous changes in graphics or even if drawRect is empty. The less pixels you have to draw over and less layers and elements are in them for the next drawing cycle the faster it will be. Consider decreasing the size of your Rect for the absolute needed ranges to draw, this will fasten it very much. And rethink your design pattern if drawRect is really the way to go for your needs. Maybe you want to compose classes that draw once at initiation and only update size and positions after.

If you want to make faster UI: it is recommended to use `-(void)layoutSubviews` instead and update the frames of your pre-defined layout/sublayers UI elements.

If really measuring is your thing: one measurement will give you only a rough clue about improvements but being more precise than performing a selector on top of your object model.

instead use

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h> 

mach_absolute_time();
```

cache the output in a global to calculate time diff on it

Traversing layout code in your `-drawRect` will give you wrong timing anyway.
DrawRect is for drawing. In other words you would place your if statement in `-(void)layoutSubviews` or `-(void)layoutSublayers`.

As on iOS your UI is usually running always in `Main Thread` you can measure before and after the allocation and initiation of your Subview containing what you want to exam. In case you want to measure changes in drawing while running you will want to figure out what of the mentioned drawing methods is called when.

Another extreme simple solution is a `NSLog(@"t");` and watching the corresponding time prints in your debugger.

Comment: I would like to measure the TOTAL time it takes to draw or redraw ALL of the subviews in a view controller. Those subviews might be table views, scroll views, all kinds of controls and images or labels. And I need to measure it as I develop my app. And I want to look at those numbers always, after every change in the code, not once in a while when I feel like using Instruments. My solution might work if all the subviews, even those from the child view controllers are drawn in a single event cycle and if the selector sent to perfomSelector: is preformed on the next event cycle.

Comment: well, then CADisplayLink is what you want to know before because you will want to draw in less than one cycle aka 60 or 120Hz. Your bottleneck will be memory allocation for caching of fetched data and corresponding worker threads (request-caching-parsing). From developing a real time motion sequencer fetching permanently data from external gear and networks while rendering  i used drawRect only on initiation but most often not at all. Just telling, drawRect is lowering your performance then because its not meant to be called permanently bound to CADisplayLink even if you can.

Comment: instead the Inspector is running inside Xcode showing the rendering pressure expressed in percent of 120Hz.